# Is it possible to run Nodejs on powerpc based Linux?

Tags: node.js, powerpc

I tried to build the latest Linux 64bit stable version with `./configure` `make` and `make install` but ended up with this error:

```
../deps/openssl/openssl/include/openssl/../../crypto/bn/bn.h:803:23: error: unknown type name ‘BN_ULONG’
```

So is it actually possible to develop nodejs apps on Debian ppc?

My setup is iMac G5 PowerPC with Debian Wheezy PPC on it.

Comment: Which version of node did you try to build? Which platform are you using? Please mention that.

Comment: Added details about nodejs version I tried

Comment: Can you try Node prerequisites given [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) and [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)

Comment: I know 5 years passed by, Did you manage to get it working on g5? At the end. Having same problem myself, trying to get nodejs working od ppc64. Versions ppc64el are not for G5 processors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Didn't try any further and sold that machine as it had some fan issues :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Andrew Low from IBM has developed a PowerPC port of node.js: https://github.com/andrewlow/node
as well as V8: https://github.com/andrewlow/v8ppc

Comment: This versions not working on G5 (power pc). We need different architecture support for G5 processors.